# IntelliJ tries to resolve local dependency in remote Apache repository

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a local dependency defined in my POM file. When I update the POM file no errors are shown. However, I cannot find the classes in the dependency inside the source code editor. When I try to reload the POM file, I receive and error message stating that the dependency could not be found in the remote Apache Maven repository.

I have checked my local Maven .m2 repository and the dependency exists inside. It seems that IntelliJ is trying to resolve a local dependency remotely. How can I get IntelliJ to use my local repository?

I tried to add a local dependency to my POM file and expected the classes in the dependency to be available inside the code editor.

Comment: Does Maven work as intended from the Command Prompt? Can you share how exactly the dependency is declared in pom.xml and if the pom.xml has any explicitly defined repositories?